# Oracle Apex: How do I tell Apex to use the value from a column to a query

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I want to know if there is a way to take the value from a column of a report (from a specific row) and use it as variable to a PL/SQL Statement:

````
DECLARE 
    CURSOR cur_PersonnelAutoComplete IS
    SELECT TASKS.ID AS TASK_ID, PERSONNEL.ID AS PERS_ID, JOBTYPES.JOB_HOURS AS PERS_WK, 
    PERSONNEL.DAILY_WAGE AS PERS_DW, PERSONNEL.STAMP AS PERS_STAMP 
    FROM DAILYWORKS JOIN PERSONNEL ON DAILYWORKS.WORKER_ID=PERSONNEL.ID 
    JOIN JOBTYPES ON PERSONNEL.JOB_TYPE=JOBTYPES.ID
    JOIN TASKS ON DAILYWORKS.WORK_ID = TASKS.ID
    WHERE TASKS.ID =:ID --(ID is a column from my report that i want to use -from this row-)
    AND PERSONNEL.ID = WORKER_ID; --(WORKER_ID is also a column from my report that i want to use -from this row-)
    
    var_emp cur_PersonnelAutoComplete%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_PersonnelAutoComplete;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_PersonnelAutoComplete INTO var_emp;
        EXIT WHEN cur_PersonnelAutoComplete%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE DAILYWORKS SET DAILY_WAGE = var_emp.PERS_DW, TEMP_EMP_TYPE = var_emp.PERS_WK,
        STAMP = var_emp.PERS_STAMP
        WHERE WORKER_ID = var_emp.PERS_ID AND WORK_ID =var_emp.TASK_ID;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_PersonnelAutoComplete;
END;```
If i run this nothing happens, but if i run the same code with page items, works perfectly!
````

Comment: where are you running this from?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible. You have provided very little information about exactly what it is you want to do with it so here are some options

- You can make it a link to another page (or to the same page with a specific request) and then execute that code in a page process. Define the column as type "Link" and then set a page item on the target page to a column value in the link builder.
- You can also fire a dynamic action with a specific column value as one of its arguments. There are quite a bit of steps to setting this up but you can find a complete example in the "Sample Dynamic Actions" application. Have a look at the "Complex - Delete and Refresh" example. That does exactly that.

Comment: No problem. Can you please mark the question as answered.